# MySQL formula convert a linear scale to a logarithmic one

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate a city "popularity" column based on the number of orders. The popularity index must be from 0 to 100.

We have this query (simplified):

```
UPDATE city INNER JOIN
    (SELECT zip, COUNT(1) popularity FROM order GROUP BY zip) AS orderCount
ON city.zip = orderCount.zip
SET city.popularity = orderCount.popularity*100/800000
```

The most popular zip had 800'000 orders.

As the order distribution is not linear, we have a few cities with very high values and most of the others with a small number.
Therefore most of the popularity is 1 or 0.

We would like to have a log scale so that we can still compare the popularity of the least popular cities.

What would be the formula to convert the popularity from a linear scale to a logarithmic one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE city INNER JOIN
    (SELECT zip, LOG(10, COUNT(1)) popularity FROM order GROUP BY zip) AS orderCount
ON city.zip = orderCount.zip
SET city.popularity = orderCount.popularity*100/GreatestValue
```

**Note** that you need to determine `GreatestValue`.

Answer (score -2):

UPDATE location INNER JOIN
    (SELECT zip, COUNT(1) popularity FROM orders GROUP BY zip) AS orderCount
SET location.popularity = archiveCount.popularity*100/800000
WHERE location.zip = archiveCount.zip;

Comment: A single statement is not very helpful. It would be better if you explain how the answer solves the problem. Also, I believe that the answer is wrong because you don't answer the question (how to smooth a non-linear distribution) and the actual SQL statement is invalid.